# Make Monitor USB ports work with Ubuntu via HDMI cable?

Tags: 20.04, usb, hdmi, monitor

I have Monitor that has 2 USB ports and also have laptop (Ubuntu) and PC desktop (Windows). I use  Displayport cable to connect Windows (also tried using HDMI on windows. USB ports work out of the box as well) and HDMI to connect to Ubuntu PC. When I shut down one and start another, correct display source is activated.

But USB ports from my Monitor are not working on Ubuntu (it works on Windows out of the box).

Is there something extra that is needed in Ubuntu to be done, so it would recognize those USB ports when Monitor is connected via HDMI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear.

You imply that you are using 1 screen with 2 separate PCs: one with Windows, one with Ubuntu.

One PC is connected via Displayport, the other via HDMI.

If that is correct, that means you need *two* host-to-client USB cables: 1 from the Windows PC, and 1 from the Ubuntu PC. If you monitor only has 1 type-B USB input socket, you will need to move the cable from one PC to the other when switching.

Comment: Oh right, I set up that long time ago and forgot that I actually used extra USB on desktop;). Thats why its working:)

Comment: In that case, do please upvote my answer. :-)